# Ajax call to ASP.NET WEB API returning error for 200 status code

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-web-api2

The goal is to make a ajax call that deletes stored searches of a user.

The method looks like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("DeleteStoredSearch")]
    public HttpResponseMessage DeleteStoredSearch(StoredSearch request)
    {
        _service.StoredSearchDelete(request.StoredSearchId);

        return new HttpResponseMessage { StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK };
    }
```

The ajax call looks like this:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://" + domain + "/buyer/api/v1_0/FacetedSearchApi/DeleteStoredSearch",
        data: { "StoredSearchId": search_id },
        success: function (result)
        {
            console.log('Successfully called');
            $this_element.closest('.listing').remove();
            var thing = document.getElementById('searchcount').innerHTML;
            var thenumber = thing.match(/\d+/)[0]
            document.getElementById('searchcount').innerHTML = thing.replace(/\d+/, thenumber - 1);
        },
        error: function (exception) {
            alert("error:" + JSON.stringify(exception));
            console.log("error:" + JSON.stringify(exception));
        }
    });
```

I get the following error:

> error:{"readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"error"}

Some help would be apreciated.

EDIT:

The call is a crossdomain, and i get the following message:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://"CAN'TSHOWTHIS"/FacetedSearchApi/DeleteStoredSearch. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin http://CAN'TSHOWTHIS.com' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Is this a cross domain request? Check the console to find the exact error

Comment: how do you know it's `200`?

Comment: It, is a cross domain request. It's 200 because i checked the status code of the request.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add below code in your `web.config`'s `<system.webServer>` section

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST, GET, OPTIONS" />
  </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
```

and enable `crossdomain` property in `$.ajax` to `true`
example

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        crossDomain: true,
        success: function (jsonResult) {
           //do what ever with the reply
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
            //handle error
        }
    });
```

Comment: I replaced the `"*"` from from `<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />` with the appropriate origin and it worked like a charm. Thank you!